# How to include a specific entry into mysql query result

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Here is my MySQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM myschool.term_reports
where class = 4 and term = 2 and year = 2018 and studentid = '19' or subject_id = 31
order by score
limit 6;
```

Now the result does not include subject_id 31 because the score is not amongst best 6 subjects. However, subject_id 31 is a key subject and it should be included in the best 6. How can I add it to the result?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by `best 6 subjects` ?

Comment: Use braces with `AND` and `OR` condition

Comment: These are the subects the student performed well. The student can sit for more than 6 subject but only best six count. Including "English".

Comment: Add some data and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Please let me know if any issue as i have not tested

```
SELECT * FROM myschool.term_reports
where class = 4 and term = 2 and year = 2018 and studentid = '19' and subjectid=31
union
SELECT * FROM myschool.term_reports
where class = 4 and term = 2 and year = 2018 and studentid = '19' 
order by score
limit 5;
```

Comment: @bingi. It is only bringing one result. The one with subject_id 31.

Comment: 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Please let me know if any issue as i have not tested

```
SELECT * FROM myschool.term_reports
WHERE class = 4
    AND term = 2
    AND year = 2018
    AND studentid = '19'
    OR subject_id = 31
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject_id = 31 THEN 0 ELSE score END limit 6;
```

Comment: With the above data, i am getting result for SELECT * 
FROM term_reports 
WHERE form_class = 4 AND term = 2 AND year = 2018 and student_id = '115' OR subject_id = 31 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject_id = 31 THEN 0 ELSE score END LIMIT 6;

Comment: This is still returning one result only. The one with subject_id 31. I want this result added to the other 5 best subjects.

Comment: can you please provide the original data set, query you are trying and the result.

Comment: SELECT * FROM ekwendeni_girls.term_reports
where form_class = 4 and term = 2 and year = 2018 and studentid = 'ekgss-18119'
order by score
limit 6;

Comment: Subject_id 31 is a key subject. I want subject_id included in the result. Whether the score is good or bad.

Comment: SELECT * FROM ekwendeni_girls.term_reports WHERE form_class = 4 AND term = 2 AND year = 2018 AND studentid = 'ekgss-18119' OR subject_id = 31 ORDER BY CASE WHEN subject_id = 31 THEN 0 ELSE score END limit 6;

Comment: did you get the result??

Comment: You are the bestest. Thanks a lot.

Comment: How can I sum score column? I tried to "select sum(score)......." but its giving me awkward results.

Comment: Sum of score for the best 6? In the same query?

Comment: Yes in the same sql please.

Comment: did you achieve this? or else can you please let me know the expected result as aggregate function will yield only one row.

Comment: Bingi, I haven't achieved this. And yes I want to return a single column only. the sum(score).